# How to disabled lazy loading for only storybook (or if possible only for Chromatic)

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, storybook, chromatic

In my React application I am using storybook and for this I have integrated chromatic where all my images are published and stored.

But for specific stories my images are missing when build pushed to Chromatic (see screenshot below for missing image):

[image]

You can see above missing images in chromatic build.

I can disabled lazy=loading in my specific component:
My component code below:

```
<div className="flex-grow px-6 place-self-center">
          <div className="h-60 ">
            <img
              src={imageUrl}
              className="px-6 pt-4 pb-10 my-0"
              height={imageHeight}
              loading="lazy" // here I can remove this line
            />
          </div>
```

But I want to disabled lazy loading only for storybook/stories or better for Chromatic only.

Answer (score -1):

You can [ignore specific DOM elements](https://www.chromatic.com/docs/ignoring-elements) by a adding a special `class` name or a `data` attribute to the target. This could be combined with a check using [isChromatic](https://www.chromatic.com/docs/ischromatic) to determine if you're in the Chromatic environment or a regular storybook.

```
// class name
<img 
  src={imageUrl}
  className="chromatic-ignore"
  ...
/>

// data attribute
<img 
  src={imageUrl}
  data-chromatic="ignore"
  ...
/>
```

That being said, you could also change the [threshold](https://www.chromatic.com/docs/threshold) for Chromatic changes to allow some visual noise when comparing the snapshots:

```
// story parameters
parameters: {
  chromatic: { diffThreshold: 0.2 },
},
```